# Dojo - How to add text to toolbar

Tags: toolbar, dojo

I have the following toolbar and I want to add the word "Buttons" at beginning of toolbar:
http://jsfiddle.net/yyzxW/

```
 <div id="toolbar1" data-dojo-type="dijit/Toolbar" style="background-color:inherit;background-image:none;border-bottom:0px;">
 <span data-dojo-type="dijit/ToolbarSeparator">Buttons:</span>
 <div data-dojo-type="dijit/form/Button" id="toolbar1.pan" data-dojo-props="iconClass:'PanIcon', showLabel:false">פאן</div>
            <div data-dojo-type="dijit/form/Button" id="toolbar1.copy" data-dojo-props="iconClass:'dijitEditorIcon dijitEditorIconCopy', showLabel:false">Copy</div>
            <div data-dojo-type="dijit/form/Button" id="toolbar1.paste" data-dojo-props="iconClass:'dijitEditorIcon dijitEditorIconPaste', showLabel:false">Paste</div>
            <!-- The following adds a line between toolbar sections-->
            <span data-dojo-type="dijit/ToolbarSeparator"></span>
            <div data-dojo-type="dijit/form/ToggleButton" id="toolbar1.bold" data-dojo-props="iconClass:'dijitEditorIcon dijitEditorIconBold', showLabel:false">Bold</div>
        </div>
```

Also , How can I do it programmatic if I create my toolbar like this :

```
 var toolbar = new Toolbar({
            id: "toolbar1",
            style: "background-color:inherit;background-image:none;border-bottom:0px;"
        });

        var btnPan = new ToggleButton({
            label: "Pan",
            id: controls.PAN,
            onClick: function () { deactivateControls(); },
            showLabel: true,
            iconClass: "ToolbarIcon Pan"
        });

        var btnZoomIn = new ToggleButton({
            label: "Zoom In",
            id: controls.ZOOM_IN,
            onClick: function () { activateControl(this.id); },
            showLabel: true,
            iconClass: "ToolbarIcon ZoomIn"
        });

        var btnZoomOut = new ToggleButton({
            label: "Zoom Out",
            id: controls.ZOOM_OUT,
            onClick: function () { activateControl(this.id); },
            showLabel: true,
            iconClass: "ToolbarIcon ZoomOut"
        });

        toolbar.addChild(btnPan);
        toolbar.addChild(btnZoomIn);
        toolbar.addChild(btnZoomOut);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

see my modify version of jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/yyzxW/3/

put this style in div

```
 <div style='float:left;margin-top:3px;'>Buttons: </div>
```

For programming code, you can use dojo.create or put-selector to create a div in toolBar.containerNode like

```
put(toolBar.containerNode, "div.yourClass", "Your text");
```

Comment: The div text isn't aligned with the buttons , its not in the center.

Comment: @Alophind you can add any css style in style='', change 3px to 5px.

Comment: Thank you , I've added button because It seemed easier :-)

Comment: @Alophind the problem of using button instead label is that it will have hover effect and tooltip effect (if you have added title property), anything button have. You need style a lot to disable these effects. But by using a label (div tag), it is really a label, you don't have any side affects. But this is a personnel choice. :)

Comment: Thank you. Will consider it :)

Comment: You are correct, In Chrome the disabled button get selected with orange frame while in firefox it doesn't.

Comment: Small update , put create divs so I used dojo.create to create span... works good.

Answer (score 1):

You could just create a disabled button.

```
<div data-dojo-type="dijit/form/Button" 
    data-dojo-props="'class': 'labelOnlyButton', disabled: true">Buttons:</div>
```

Use `.labelOnlyButton` to create css to make it look how you want.

Comment: I've create it like this : var btnTitle = new ToggleButton({
                label: "Buttons:",                                
                showLabel: true,
                disabled: true,
                class: "labelOnlyButton"                
            });
And I can change the background color for example , but the "color" attribute won't change, its still disabled.

Comment: What is the css rule?  Your css rule will need to be more specific than the rule that changes the color.  See my fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/cswing/RDxjv/

Comment: It works now , in order to change the color I had to do this rule :
.claro .dijitButtonDisabled ,  .claro .dijitToggleButtonDisabled .dijitButtonNode 
{
    color:Black;
}

Comment: I don't think this is a good way to just add a text into toolbar. see my answer. Even you style it as a label, it still have some side effects. and you need overwrite .dijitButtonxxxx styles and that's hard to maintenance and will failed if those style changed by dojo in the future(who knows?).

Comment: @SeanZhao You are correct , I've answered in your answer and accepted it. Thank you for the info.